# I cannot find my question of chat. Please help

Tags: support

In chat I asked about effects of H2B on academia in USA,
my question was kindly forwarded to some other part of StackExchange, I think it was more a year ago.
what should I do? I tried to google it, but it was so many months ago. I cannot find and navigate my chat history.

Comment: For a second I thought you had asked about the impact of the HB2 law on academia in the USA…

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [Does the H-1B visa program cause a net decrease in the employment prospects of skilled U.S. job applicants in STEM fields?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32382/does-the-h-1b-visa-program-cause-a-net-decrease-in-the-employment-prospects-of-s).

In general, you can click on your own user card in chat to see your [chat profile](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/172548/ssimon?tab=general). That page includes a "search for messages containing" search fields where you can search for e.g. [messages you have written containing the word "job"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=172548&q=job) and then click on the [link to the relevant message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2496?m=28790853#28790853) to see the chat transcript.

Comment: thank you, how long chat histories can stay? are these chats erasable? how long it will last on stackexchange